# Is it possible to use Web API project as a full scale web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, partial-views

I am trying to implement a feature in an application that will show some data on a Google map. It will call a web api service in an iframe on the page where it will be shown. 
What I want is and thinking whether that is possible or not is, the web api receives the request, calls an external API which returns an xml. Web api takes the xml, processes it and generates a view (or partial view) i.e. cshtml and returns it to the application that had requested it. By doing so I will have a common backend and in future if there is another application (which surely will exist soon in future) that needs slightly different data, can share the same backend and then the web api, depending on which application has requested it, could return the repsective view to it.

So can we today use web api application as a full scale web application that can return views? 
Or any ideas how can I do it using MVC 5 or 6?

Comment: WebAPI won't be able to return a view... You have to use MVC controller/ for that that actually works very very similar to WebAPI. So instead of WebAPI handling the request you will have to handle it using MVC controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this would work:

1. Browser/client calls MVC action
2. MVC action calls web service, retrieving XML
3. MVC action transforms XML into a view model
4. View model is passed to CSHTML View to generate
5. View is returned to client

You can call MVC actions using AJAX requests and get back HTML responses.  WebAPI is more appropriate for REST style interfaces that returns data (xml/json) rather than HTML.  **In this case you want to return HTML, so MVC is the more direct approach.**

The fact that you want to call some web service in an intermediate step doesn't change that.  Whether you were doing either way, if inside the action method you need to call a web service, you can use a HttpClient or similar utility to make that call.

Here is some **pseudo code** to demonstrate

```
// this method called from browser client
public ActionResult SomeMvcAction(int someId)
{
     MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
     using(var client = new HttpClient())
     {
        // retrieve XML from web service
        // pump data into view model
        vm.Items = xml.Select(...);
     }

     return View("SomeViewName", vm); // pass view model to view to return HTML
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, is it only that Webapi is less appropriate for returning HTML or we can't do it using that?

Comment: @Syed: applications that have a UI are made using MVC. If they subsequently request data then they also implement WebAPI controllers. Within the same app. So the answer to your question here is **yes**, MVC is used for views (HTML) and WebAPI for data (JSON/XML).

Comment: @Rober Koritnik: Alright, that's cool. because seems like this will land closer to what I had suggested as a solution. Then my next question will be that is it possible that a webapi end point is called from my application, then webapi calls the external API and receives xml. Then it sends that xml to an MVC controller in same project/app which eventually returns it to the client that had requested it?

Comment: @Syed You can't handoff the request that was initiated against WebAPI and instead have MVC return the result.  That doesn't accomplish anything.  If you want to return HTML to the client, initiate the request to MVC. I don't udnerstand why you think that is not applicable to your situation?

Comment: Ok I do it like this, MVC controller receives an ajax call and asks WebApi controller to get it the xml it needs. So WebApi returns it the xml and then MVC controller takes care of from there and returns a view (cshtml). 
But then I need help regarding how to do that. I mean how to call a WebApi controller from MVC one (both in same app/project side by side).

Comment: @Syed where is the XML ultimately coming from? a webservice that is outside of your application?

Comment: @Syed: Yes, you can easily call a WebAPI controller action from your MVC controller action. But you will have to instantiate WebAPI controller manually. **But**. If that specific WebAPI controller action doesn't get called from the client side, then it doesn't make much sense to have it in WebAPI. For such things it's better to have a services layer (library project) that does the external data handling. And then use this service from either MVC or WebAPI where appropriate.

Comment: It doesn't sound like WebAPI serves any purpose here.  As I demonstrate with pseudo code, you can call the external webservice directly from MVC.  WebAPI is NOT for MAKING web service calls.  It is for receiving web service calls.  Just because you are making a web service call, doesn't mean WebAPI needs to be involved.  You can use a client library from MVC to make web service calls.

Comment: @AaronLS yes, it is coming from an external web service.

Comment: I got what you guys are trying to say. I shall go with the solution proposed by AaronLS.

Comment: @AaronLS how do I call the webservice that is located at,for example, http://t1server.com/t1api/t1/GetUserInfo. This GetuserInfo method of api returns the xml. 
And is there a way I can map the returned xml into json?